# Polynomials and harmonic functions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Let a real number $C > 0$. Show that if $v$ is harmonic and satisfies the estimate $$|v(x)| \leq C(1 + |x|^n),$$ then $v$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

I tried to use the fact that every harmonic function is analytic and use the theory of complex variables. However, I couldn't resolve it.

Comment: Hint: Use the Cauchy estimates for harmonic functions.

Comment: If you give up this is Theorem 2.16.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.07941.pdf#page75